# DRY Coding in Laravel 7+

Tags: laravel

I have been using Laravel as a beginner for a few weeks now and i am seeking for knowledge.
I hope that you can help me!

I would like to clean up my project and its controllers.
I have two api refresh buttons which retrieves new orders and updates existing orders from an api.
One button is for a specific costcentre and the other button is for refreshing all orders at the same time.
Not to forget, it also updates the OrderProduct rows.

For this i have used the same code with just a little difference for each function.
While i like to not repeat the same.

Is there any solution for this?

Example current situation:

**Specific costcentre**

```php
$order = new Order();
$order->costcentre_id = $costcentre->id;
$order->invoice = $row['invoice_prefix'] . $row['invoice_no'];
$order->customer_id = $row['customer_id'];
$order->firstname = $row['firstname'];
$order->lastname = $row['lastname'];
$order->email = $row['email'];
$order->telephone = $row['telephone'];
$order->save();

foreach ($product as $prod) {
    $newprod = new Product();
    $newprod->name = $prod->name;
    $newprod->save();
}
```

**All costcentres**

```php
foreach ($costcentre as $cc) {
    $order = new Order();
    $order->costcentre_id = $cc->id;
    $order->invoice = $row['invoice_prefix'] . $row['invoice_no'];
    $order->customer_id = $row['customer_id'];
    $order->firstname = $row['firstname'];
    $order->lastname = $row['lastname'];
    $order->email = $row['email'];
    $order->telephone = $row['telephone'];
    $order->save();

    foreach ($product as $prod) {
        $newprod = new Product();
        $newprod->name = $prod->name;
        $newprod->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `action` pattern https://stitcher.io/blog/laravel-beyond-crud-03-actions

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier this is golden, thank you!

Comment: Ps. i also found this:
https://medium.com/@remi_collin/keeping-your-laravel-applications-dry-with-single-action-classes-6a950ec54d1d